# VimeJs subtitles not displaying when using Hls

Tags: reactjs, vimejs

I'm using VimeJs Hls to stream video.

and grabbing a vtt file from a cdn.

Here is what I tried:

1.Using the same VTT file with the < Video /> provider with an mp4 file, plays the video and the subtitles are showing.

2.Using the same VTT file with the < Hls /> provider with a m3u8 file plays the video but doesn't display the subtitles.

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import '@vime/core/themes/default.css';
import { Player, Ui, Video, Hls } from '@vime/react';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Player controls>
      {/* Provider component is placed here. */}
      <FirstProvider />
      {/* <SecondProvider /> */}
      <Ui>{/* UI components are placed here. */}</Ui>
    </Player>
  );
}


const FirstProvider = () => (
  <Video crossOrigin="" poster="https://media.vimejs.com/poster.png">
    {/* These are passed directly to the underlying HTML5 `<video>` element. */}
    {/* Why `data-src`? Lazy loading, you can always use `src` if you prefer.  */}
    <source
      data-src="https://media.vimejs.com/720p.mp4"
      type="video/mp4"
    />

    <track
      default
      kind="subtitles"
      src="https://cc.2cdns.com/16/d6/16d6e74bf6ab3cc89cb80d523d0aea47/eng-2.vtt"
      srcLang="en"
      label="English"
    />
  </Video>
)

const SecondProvider = () => (
  <Hls crossOrigin="" poster="https://media.vimejs.com/poster.png">
    <source
      data-src="https://c-3.dokicloud.one/_v8/7e93e434d479b1e7d3468cb3859004cfceb53e8b4b8d625a2ed9b915c22bb21ececf7e991c74a3ab21ec244c564870dd9d62599850f1b17bd3bee2a52eef67e7667f713cdb84f7e4875c8168d43aa2ffe11da669f995a5ca61ee21475e66a307ae4c2a565adb930ee82922df63a5346e65480f90421c42c998808ab02bc7b760/playlist.m3u8"
      type="application/x-mpegURL"
    />
    <track
      default
      kind="subtitles"
      src="https://cc.2cdns.com/16/d6/16d6e74bf6ab3cc89cb80d523d0aea47/eng-2.vtt"
      srcLang="en"
      label="English"
    />
  </Hls>
)
```

Is this related to the way HLS videos are treated?
I think it's because the hls video can't sync the timestamps to the vtt file.

any idea how I can display the subtitles on a m3u8 file?